# Keep sound on when switching users on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, audio, pulse-audio

What do I got to do to stop user switching on Linux from stopping sound?

If I play some audio under user `user1`, I don't want it to stop
when I switch to an unused virtual console or to `user2` (via Menu->Log Out->Switch User).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the sound turns off is that Pulseaudio is started on each login with this user's privileges and the system does not allow users to listen to other users audio.

Solution :

1. Add all users that should be able play back to the *pulse-access* group

   ```
   adduser <user-name> pulse-access
   ```
2. Create */etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service* with the following content:

   ```
   [Service]
   Type=simple
   PIDFile=/var/run/pulse/pid
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=yes --system=yes --disallow-module-loading=yes --disallow-exit=yes

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
3. Enable this new systemd service so that it is started on boot:

   ```
   systemctl enable pulseaudio
   ```
4. Be aware that this configuration is

   - less secure (e.g. other users can listen to your microphone)
   - sound output will not automatically switch to and from headphones anymore
   - might prevent Bluetooth from working.

Source and more information in the post :
[How to prevent sound mute when switching user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382601/how-to-prevent-sound-mute-when-switching-user)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a HOWTO for systemd-less  (upstart-based) distros?

Comment: Sorry, don't know of one.